# How To bind an image from WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having set of images and those paths are defined in a xaml file like below

```
<BitmapImage
        x:Key="LoginLogo"
        UriSource="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/LoginLogo.png" />
```

And in my view.xaml am having an image control and Source property is bound with View Model.

Property in view model :

```
private BitMapImage _imageSource
public BitmapImage ImageSource
        {
            get { return (_imageSource); }
            set { this.SetValue(_imageSource, value); }
        }
```

Now i need to set value to Image Source . How to set this.

Comment: You didn't try `<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}">`? Besides that, what's the relation between your view model's ImageSource property and the XAML-defined BitmapImage resource?

Comment: @Clemens and changing ImageSource from BitmapImage to string

Comment: @MightyBadaboom For what reason? While you may argue if it's good practice, it is perfectly legal to have a VM property of type BitmapImage.

Comment: @Clemens Having the Image in your ViewModel would not be the cleanest way when following the MVVM pattern. Your ViewModel should not know how the View is using the uri of the image.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom That's plain wrong, besides that there is no knowledge of any URI in the VM. There is just a property of type BitmapImage, nothing more. The view model knows nothing about the view.

Answer (score 2):

You would bind the `Source` property of an Image control to the view model property like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}">
```

---

Setting the view model property to the BitmapImage resource would perhaps look like shown below (e.g. in the MainWindow class):

```
viewModel.ImageSource = (BitmapImage)Resources["LoginLogo"];
```

---

You may also consider to change the type of your view model property from `BitmapImage` to the base class `ImageSource`. This would provide greater flexibility in terms of the different image types you may assign to the property, e.g. `DrawingImage` or `BitmapFrame` etc.

---

An alternative would be a view model property of type `Uri` (or `string`) holding the image URL

```
private Uri imageUrl
public Uri ImageUrl
{
    get { return imageUrl; }
    set { SetValue(imageUrl, value); }
}
```

You would bind it the same way, like `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">` (and thus benefit from built-in automatic type conversion), but could save the BitmapImage resource and directly assign a property value like this:

```
viewModel.ImageUrl =
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/LoginLogo.png");
```

Comment: Beware of using `Binding` for images as `WPF` will lock the file for the (duration of execution) of the application. From my experience using a converter on the image source property and then returning a bitmap image is much safer.

Comment: There is no file involved. The question is about an assembly resource. For local files, a binding converter should set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.